# List only outdated pip packages mentioned in requirements file

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I can use `pip list -o` to get a list of outdated packages but I would like to only get a list of outdated packages which are listed in a particular requirements file. Basically the equivalent of `pip freeze -r requirements.txt` for outdated packages.

I could use [`--not-required`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/#options) but this would still list packages installed which are installed but not listed in the requirements file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/259474/find-outdated-updatable-pip-packages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this tool: https://github.com/simion/pip-upgrader

All you have to do is the following:

```
pip install pip-upgrader
pip-upgrade
```

This then walks you through all packages that can be upgraded in the `requirements.txt` in an interactive fashion.

Comment: As of March 25, 2021, [pip-upgrader](https://github.com/simion/pip-upgrader) is unmaintained. The author of pip-upgrader is using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Came up with a solution in form of a `bash` snippet while writing the question:

```sh
join -t= \
  <(python -m pip list -o --format=freeze | sort) \
  <(awk -F== '{ print $1 }' requirements.txt | sort)
```

Comment: "ERROR: List format 'freeze' cannot be used with the --outdated option."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade your dependencies *without* also upgrading your `requirements.txt`, you can utilize `pip install --upgrade`. This will only make sense if your `requirements.txt` doesn't freeze exact versions, but rather provides either no version requirements at all, or allows version ranges. You can then utilize `pip install --report`:

```bash
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt --dry-run --report - --quiet 2> /dev/null \
    | jq -r '.install[] | "\(.metadata.name)  \(.metadata.version)"'
```

Since `pip install --report` is printing a report in JSON, you'll need [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). By now basically any distribution should have it in its repository, if it's not already pre-installed.

You might want to think about using `pip install --user`.

Let me explain:

- (`pip install`) `--upgrade` tells `pip` to not only check whether the required packages are installed, but also whether there are newer versions of the required packages available
- (`pip install`) `-r requirements.txt` tells `pip` to read the packages to install from your `requirements.txt`
- (`pip install`) `--dry-run` tells `pip` to only print what it would do (i.e. don't install anything)
- (`pip install`) `--report -` tells `pip` to create a JSON report about what it does (or better: would do since `--dry-run` was given); the `-` tells `pip` to print the report to stdout
- (`pip install`) `--quiet` and the `>&2 /dev/null` pipe tells `pip` to not output anything and interfere with report generation
- `jq` reads `pip`'s report from STDIN and prints the package name and latest version of available updates in the form `name-of-package  version-of-package` (the report JSON looks like the following: `{ "install": [ { "metadata": { "name": "name-of-first-package", "version": "version-of-first-package", … }, … }, { "metadata": { "name": "name-of-second-package", "version": "version-of-second-package", … }, … }, … ], … }`)

Here's an example:

```
$ pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt --dry-run --report - --quiet 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.install[] | "\(.metadata.name)  \(.metadata.version)"'
imaplib2  3.6
urllib3  1.25.11
```